# Admob - RNAMobRewardedVideoAdModule is not abstract

Tags: reactjs, react-native, admob

Steps:

```
react-native init App
npm i react-native-admob -S
react-native link
react-native run-android
```

Error:
[Show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb23T.png)

> error: RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule is not abstract and does not override abstract method onRewardedVideoCompleted() in RewardedVideoAdListener
>   public class RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements RewardedVideoAdListener

Archive **RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule**

```
package com.sbugert.rnadmob;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;

public class RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule extends 
ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements RewardedVideoAdListener {
RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;
String adUnitID;
String testDeviceID;
Callback requestAdCallback;
Callback showAdCallback;

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "RNAdMobRewarded";
}

public RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
}

@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
    WritableMap reward = Arguments.createMap();

    reward.putInt("amount", rewardItem.getAmount());
    reward.putString("type", rewardItem.getType());

    sendEvent("rewardedVideoDidRewardUser", reward);
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    sendEvent("rewardedVideoDidLoad", null);
    requestAdCallback.invoke();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    sendEvent("rewardedVideoDidOpen", null);
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    sendEvent("rewardedVideoDidStart", null);
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    sendEvent("rewardedVideoDidClose", null);
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    sendEvent("rewardedVideoWillLeaveApplication", null);
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    WritableMap event = Arguments.createMap();
    String errorString = null;

    switch (errorCode) {
        case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR:
        errorString = "ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR";
        break;
        case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST:
        errorString = "ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST";
        break;
        case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR:
        errorString = "ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR";
        break;
        case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL:
        errorString = "ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL";
        break;
    }

    event.putString("error", errorString);
    sendEvent("rewardedVideoDidFailToLoad", event);
    requestAdCallback.invoke(errorString);
}

private void sendEvent(String eventName, @Nullable WritableMap params) {
    getReactApplicationContext().getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit(eventName, params);
}

@ReactMethod
public void setAdUnitID(String adUnitID) {
    this.adUnitID = adUnitID;
}

@ReactMethod
public void setTestDeviceID(String testDeviceID) {
    this.testDeviceID = testDeviceID;
}

@ReactMethod
public void requestAd(final Callback callback) {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule.this.mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(getCurrentActivity());

            RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule.this.mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule.this);

            if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                callback.invoke("Ad is already loaded."); // TODO: make proper error
            } else {
                requestAdCallback = callback;

                AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();

                if (testDeviceID != null){
                    if (testDeviceID.equals("EMULATOR")) {
                        adRequestBuilder = adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
                    } else {
                        adRequestBuilder = adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(testDeviceID);
                    }
                }

                AdRequest adRequest = adRequestBuilder.build();
                mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(adUnitID, adRequest);
            }
        }
    });
}

@ReactMethod
public void showAd(final Callback callback) {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                showAdCallback = callback;
                mRewardedVideoAd.show();
            } else {
                callback.invoke("Ad is not ready."); // TODO: make proper error
            }
        }
    });
}

@ReactMethod
public void isReady(final Callback callback) {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            callback.invoke(mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded());
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some versions (don't ask which one) of com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener requires onRewardedVideoCompleted function. RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule class implements that class.

If you don't want to manage gms versions you can just create an empty function. I can't find any javascript call to that method anyway.

RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule.java

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted(){

}
```

If your version of react-native-admob has onRewardedVideoCompleted function and you are getting 'method doesnt override' error, then remove the @override annotation from method.

Kindly refer this link for the answer https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/issues/316